# Can't find the element although the xpath seems to be correct

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rselenium

I'm trying to scrape some data from the page with the interactive map. And I got completely stuck. I can easily locate the element in HTML in the browser however Rselenium xpath fails to find it (although I'm pretty sure that the xpath itself is correct). The element is not located in iframe, it also doesn't require clicking something before it is actually visible so that is what makes it a real quest for me cause I don't know what the reason might be.

Actually there are only two lines of html I can find with xpath: the body and the iframe which is just after it, therefore there are many scripts (loading all the map resources) and after those scripts there is the rest of HTML code. I can't really show it here cause it is huge. I can provide the link to the site and the procedure to get to the point where I got stuck.

http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/imap/Imgp_2.html?gpmap=gp0&locale=en

This is the link. There you need to:
1. click searches -> searching for plots. 
2. At the right side of the screen the search bar will appear. There you may put "Smolec 300" (its just some working example). 
3. After that you click the list which appears below the input, click next time where is "precint: Smolec"

After all that you should get something like this:
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3iyN.png). At the picture you can see the info bar with the arrow which points to the plot you have chosen (Smolec 300). And here is where I'm stuck. I can easily find the html of that arrow in the browser but can't find it with xpath in selenium.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming it is not confidential. could you provide the link of said side you are referring to, so we can answer your question for you?

Comment: Ok, I have added the link and instruction to it to the post.

Comment: I didn't look at the HTML but it seems that some web services are available from the geoportal. It might be much easier to use them rather than reverse engineer the map. See there (in particular API service): https://www.geoportal.gov.pl/uslugi